# Local maximums of cosine

Tags: sequences-and-series

"$f(x)=\cos(x)-\cos(x^2)+\cos(x^3)-\cos(x^4)\cdots + (-1)^{n-1}\cos(x^n)$. Find the number of local maximums of $f(x)$ for $0 \leq x \leq n$."

How would you even go about starting a problem like this? I was thinking that I might use the second derivative test, but I don't really understand how I would do that because $f(x)$ is a sum. Thanks!

Comment: Have you graphed a few of these functions. Things get out of hand quite quickly.

Comment: Yeah, I graphed the functions.

Comment: perhaps taylor series?

Comment: I tried doing that too but I don't see much of a pattern in the sum of that I can use.